# Enforce naming/folder pattern while creating branch in Azure Repos

Tags: azure-devops, repository, branch, azure-repos

I want to enforce a policy at my azure repository where branch name should start only with feature/* OR hotfix/* etc. If any other name is given then it should not be possible to create that named branch.

so **feature/test** should be created but **test** should not.

Can you please help for it?

Thanks

Comment: Git itself does not (and cannot) enforce this; hosting sites can add all kinds of rules though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can enforce a policy at repo name.

For a workaround, you  can restrict users to only create branches under feature  by setting Repo permissions.

You can use tf command to achieve the goal:

1.Block the Create Branch permission at the repository root for the project's contributors.

```
tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:[FabrikamProject]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam-fiber/ /teamproject:FabrikamProject /repository:FabrikamRepo
```

2.Allow users/groups to create branches under feature.

```
tf git permission /allow:CreateBranch /group:[FabrikamProject]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam-fiber/ /teamproject:FabrikamProject /repository:FabrikamRepo /branch:feature
```

If you want to limit users, you can change `/group:` -> `/user:`

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Require branches to be created in folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: Can you please help me to use it for Azure repo? I am not able to figure out how should i can apply for azure repo.  @kevin-lu-msft

Comment: Yes. We can use these command on Azure Repo.  collection -> Org URL , teamproject -> Project name , repository -> Azure Repo Name

Comment: Then it will only enable the permission to create branch under feature branch.

Comment: I agree that we can do it via tf git permission cmds. In that case we have a dependency on visual studio's Developer command prompt. I need to know if there is any other way than this?

thanks in advance

Comment: @rpshgupta Other than that, I am afraid that there is no other methods. In Azure DevOps UI, we are not able to set the create branch permission at feature branch. We can only achieve this via tf command.